# What do percentiles tell us about exponential families

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, exponential-family

I have a question in my lecture slides which asks the following

> Exponential families of distributions, such as the normal, Poisson,
>   and binomial distributions, are characterized by a very
>   fast (exponentially) decreasing density around their mode. How are the
>   standard deviation and the percentiles 25/75 related, in terms of the
>   relative distance to the mean?

I could see how the distributions are computed but could not understand how different measures relate and influence each other.

Comment: For normal case it is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range#Interquartile_range_of_distributions. For Binomial case, since it is descrite, you can easily calculate the relation for any parameters.

Comment: how would the above question work if i get more specific and consider just the poisson distribution

Comment: You can adapt this code in R for your purposes: ```start <- 5;
end <- 1000;
quantiles <- sapply(seq(start, end), function(x) {return(x - qpois(0.75, x))});
sds <- sqrt(seq(start:end));
plot(sds ~ quantiles)```. The relatioinship can be seen from the plot. You should change 0.75 to 0.25 for opposite case.

Comment: @Xi'an I think it's a sane question. The normal (empirical) probability laws only apply to one family of distributions, and Chebyshev's probability are perhaps too conservative for some practical distributions. Could you come up with normal probability bounds based on mean $\pm$ sd intervals for exponential family distributions? It's like the "just-right porridge" of Goldilocks' probability bounds.

Comment: @AdamO: thank you for the comments but I afraid I still do not understand the point. Theoretically, there is nothing I can say in general towards connecting the standard deviation and the interquartile range.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the relation between those two quantities for the Poisson, you get somewhat of an equivalence:

[image]

For a comparison, if you represent 4 times the standard deviation (range of the Normal 95% interval) against the 95% interquantile range, you get the following:

[image]

And here is a similar representation for the exponential distribution, with a rather close connection between standard deviation and interquartile range:

[image]